# Why is ",/default.aspx" being appended to the end of my URL

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect

I have a weird situation ...
I have a redirect to a url and when I look at the HTML in inspect element is is as follows: http://myTestsite.net/home/default.aspx, but when you click on the link it renders as "https://myTestsite.net/home/default.aspx,/default.aspx ... causing an error. any advice?

Here is the code : note: targetPath is "%20default.aspx"

```
  string targetPath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Core.Context.Current.Url);
                string secure = SiteUtil.IsSecureConnection(Request) ? "https://" : "http://";
                string targetDomain = Digitaria.Web.MBFI.UI.Data.Util.MobileCookieOverrideUtil.GetCookieOverrideMobileDomain(false);
                string viewFullLink = string.Format(@"<li><a href=""http://{0}/{1}?mode={2}&path={3}"">{4}</a></li>", targetDomain, "handlers/MobileSwitch.aspx", 1, targetPath, L.Full_Website).Replace("&", "&amp;");
                phNav.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(viewFullLink));

                phNav.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</ul>"));
```

Comment: Are you saying when you click on a http link... the request is going as https?

Comment: I would recommend looking at your route mapping.

Comment: correct ... it is flipping to "https" and appending ,/default.aspx

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel  can you post that code here?

Comment: I am not certain what you mean, I have been through the code in debug mode several times, I didn't write it and the end result does NOT Have the ,/default.aspx added. I am asking if anyone knows of a setting that I am missing?